Using cylindrical coordinates to evaluate a triple integral
Using cylindrical coordinates, calculate the value of the integral
$$\iiint_D \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \, dV$$
where
$$D = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^2 + y^2 \leq 361, 0 \leq z \leq 19 \}$$.
We have the following:
• $x^2 + y^2 = 361$
$r^2 = 361$
so $r = 19$
$0 \le r \le 19$
• $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$
The integral becomes:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{19} \int_0^{19} r \sqrt{r^2 + z^2} \ dz \ dr \ d\theta.$$
Is what I’ve done so far correct? Is there a way to simplify it, so that we don’t have to deal with $$\sqrt{r^2+z^2}$$
?

The inner integral is a simple trig sub.

What you have done so far is correct. Note that the primitive of $r\sqrt{r^2+z^2}$ with respect to $r$ is given by $\frac{1}{3}(r^2+z^2)^{3/2}$, hence
$$
\begin{align}
 I &= \int_0^{19}\mathrm{d}r \int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta \int_0^{19}\mathrm{d}z \; r\sqrt{r^2+z^2} \\
   &= 2\pi \int_0^{19} \left[\frac{1}{3}(r^2+z^2)^{3/2}\right]_{r=0}^{r=19} \mathrm{d}z \\ 
   &= \frac{2\pi}{3} \int_0^{19} \left((19^2+z^2)^{3/2} - z^3\right) \mathrm{d}z
\end{align}
$$
The last term can be integrated straightforwardly, while the first one can be handled through the change of variable $z = 19\sinh t$, which leads to
$$
I = \frac{2\pi}{3} \left(\int_0^{\operatorname{arcsinh}(1)} (19\cosh t)^4 \,\mathrm{d}t - \left[\frac{1}{4}z^4\right]_{z=0}^{z=19}\right).
$$
Then, you can reduce the fourth power of the hyperbolic cosine with the help of the usual power-reduction formulas and I let you finish from there.
